# How should I store an s3 file location in an RDS MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I am new to databases and am trying to design a simple system that will do the following :

1. Store Topics
2. Store one or many SubTopics related to those topics
3. Store file location for files related to the subtopics

Right now I am trying to use a unique identifier for each id instead of just int or bigint. I then have 3 different tables for each of the sections. I think I just store the file location as a string but how will I know the appropriate size?

Thanks in advance and I am really new to this so any constructive help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a metadata table that has more information about each save file. 
Like 
ID, fileName, originalFileName, pathOnS3, etc.
The Id can be the name of the file on S3 and you can pull the information of the file using that Id from the metadata table.

Comment: Thanks that was what I was thinking but for the fileName is there a rule-of-thumb/best practice for the length of the string that should be?

Comment: I don't think there is one, it could be a random string or a readable string.

Comment: It can be almost anything, but you can check amazon documentation for the best practices file names